Вставка виджета Dikidi на сайт Tilda
Добавил виджеты на сайт по данной инструкции: https://support.dikidi.net/ru/knowledge-bases/4/articles/295-ustanovka-vidzheta-onlajn-zapisi-dikidi-na-tilda, на версии для ПК работает, как надо, открываеться на фоне сайта, но если открыть с мобильного, то отправляет на сайт Dikidi.
Вот видео: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/R5WSjxVzIhxXOw
